# Does a database connection closes if the user leaves the page in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm creating a web based application using Java Server Faces (JSF). I'm just wondering if a database connection is open and the user leaves the web page (close the browser), does JSF automatically closes this connection?

Comment: Do you use JPA or manage db connections by yourself?

Comment: What are you telling it to do, computers don't think for themselves ...

Comment: No I did not used JPA I just manage the connection by myself.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Like I said, I'm just wondering. Of course computers don't think for themselves that's why I put "does JSF".

Comment: The one who's responsible for opening any resource is also responsible for closing it. JSF surely doesn't magically open any DB connections by itself and so won't close it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the database connection immediately after getting your data to send back to the client - BEFORE sending it back to the client. Best to do it in a `finally` block. There is no real reason to keep it open but it does not only introduce a potential memory leak but also a great security risk.

Comment: Is that ok to open and close a database connection every transaction? That's my current approach in my application. I think that would be too much burden for the server so I'm thinking of another way to deal with it. Will database pooling solve this problem?

Comment: To open a new connection for every transaction is the standard approach. But you're right, connection pooling does improve performance. Good point!

Answer (score 3):

User leaving the page cannot have an effect on the database connection. A user requests a page, the server responds. That is the end of the their intercommunication. If the user closes the browser or presses back the server is not notified of this.

The only place you can close it is in your Java code before you create the HTTP response.

Comment: It depends on the scope of the managed bean. ViewSoped and RequestScoped beans will be removed if the server gets a new request (different page) from the same session. Of course closing the browser is not detected by the server until session time out.

Comment: Yes, but the user closing the browser has no such effect. And a new request still means executing some Java code to generate a new HTTP response etc.

Answer (score 0):

The database connection closes if you close it, or the connection pool if any closes it, or it gets garbage collected.